# About symfony 3.4.8 service autowiring

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm using symfony version 3.4.8.
The configuration works in symfony 3.3, but in symfony 3.4 I get:

```
Cannot autowire service "ProblemBundle\EntityManager\ProblemManager": argument "$paginator" of metho  
  d "__construct()" references interface "Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface" but no such service   
  exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

ProblemManager.php

```
public function (PaginatorInterface $page){}
```

app/config/services.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: true

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'


    UserBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/UserBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        autowire: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    UserBundle\EntityManager\UserManager:
        autowire: true

    ProblemBundle\EntityManager\ProblemManager:
        autowire: true
        public: true
```

How can I configure autowiring for all (including third party bundle)?

Comment: The fact that you had it working in 3.3 but not in 3.4 is a bit puzzling.  From the console, run "bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep Knp" and see if PaginatorInterface is defined as it should be.  And the fact that the error message references $paginator but your posted ProblemManager constructor has $page is also very strange.

Comment: It should work in the latest version of the paginator bundle but until you upgrade you could just use `Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface: '@knp_paginator'` to set alias that interface to the underlying service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruct the Dependency Injection component which implementation would you like to use, for instance:

```
Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface:
    public: true
    alias: Your\Solid\Implementation
```

Should you want to use another implementation, it's a matter of changing this single configuration line.

Comment: about it can you give me more about document?i confuse for it.

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry.

Comment: about you comment i can't find it in symfony office document?thanks

Comment: @emix Just for info, out of the box, PaginatorInterface is already defined.  Conversely, SlidingPagination is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can still inject `Non-Autowireable` arguments by service tags, in your case it would be

```
   ProblemBundle\EntityManager\ProblemManager:
    autowire: true
    public: true
    arguments:
        $page: "@knp_paginator.injectable"
```

see: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: Why would injecting a string instead of an object help?

Comment: From sample, it seems he is using `KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle`. And in their documentation, to inject the service they have mentioned this tag `knp_paginator.injectable` DIC tag. It's a tag for the service, not string. Thanks! see: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: Have you tried it?  As written in your answer, it is a string.  Not a service.  Don't mean to be harsh but it is clear that the person asking the question is pretty much clueless when it comes to service definition.  So when you propose an alternative approach to a correct answer then it really does need to work.  Make a simple test case and you will see.

Comment: Ah..My mistake, should work now, I have used similar approach many times...updated the answer. And yes, it's alternative to other answer. Thanks!

Comment: Injecting a service is better.  Still not sure where you got the .injectable from.  A fresh install does not show it as being defined.  There is of course a PaginatorInterface defined.  Which really implies the problem is somewhere else completely.